# Spring boot vaadin project @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I am using spring boot vaadin project.I have a repository like this:`public interface PersonneRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {}`

I want to instantiate this repository in my class .In Ui and in Views I do this:
@Autowired
PersonneRepository repo; 
this work easily but in simple class(public class x{}) repo return null .And I don't like to passe it in parameter or session .Have you any idea please?

Comment: the only way things get autowired in a class is if the class itself gets created during initial scanning. If you create in manually SomeClass class = new SomeClass(); autowired will not work! Could this be your problem?

Comment: Yes I create my class ith SomeClass class = new SomeClass(); But how can I create it during initial scanning?

Comment: If you annotate it as `@Component` (or `@Service` or whatever it is) then yes. You only need to figure out what `@Scope` it should have, as by [default it's set to singleton](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inject dependencies the dependent classes have to be managed by Spring. This can be achieved with the class annotation `@Component`:

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

For use in Vaadin classes `@SpringComponent` it's recommended:

> Alias for {@link org.springframework.stereotype.Component} to prevent conflicts with {@link com.vaadin.ui.Component}.

Example:

```
@Repository // Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository", it's a specialized form of @Component
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    // Spring generates a singleton proxy instance with some common CRUD methods
}

@UIScope // Implementation of Spring's {@link org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope} that binds the UIs and dependent beans to the current {@link com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession}
@SpringComponent
public class SomeVaadinClassWichUsesTheRepository {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired // setter injection to allow simple mocking in tests
    public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    /**
     * The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.
     */ 
    @PostConsruct
    public init() {
        // do something with personRepository, e.g. init Vaadin table...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Mr Agassner but how can I access to SomeVaadinClassWichUsesTheRepository with SomeVaadinClassWichUsesTheRepository x = new SomeVaadinClassWichUsesTheRepository()???

Comment: inject it with autowired ;)

Comment: I found my problem is in the name of my package and @ComponentScan . Thank you .But now in window I have the same problem null